# Qualtrics: Have specific subjects receive specific pictures to rate

Tags: qualtrics

I created a Qualtrics project to have subjects rate faces. I uploaded faces to the graphics library. I used Loop & Merge to repeat the same question for different faces.

How can I have a specific subject rate specific faces?

For example, consider a comma-separated-value file (or JavaScript code, or Python code, ...), with the following two lines:

```
123,31,41,59
124,26,31,41
```

- Subject 123 should rate face 31, face 41, and face 59.
- Subject 124 should rate face 26, face 31, and face 41.

(A face could have an alternate name, such a Qualtrics-generated image name.)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the faces to your contact list, so your csv contact list upload would look like:

```
ExternalDataReference,face1,face2,face3
123,31,41,59
124,26,31,41
```

Then pipe the face variables into your loop & merge setup:

```
1 ${e://Field/face1}
2 ${e://Field/face2}
3 ${e://Field/face3}
```

Comment: I am not that familiar with contact lists. Could Qualtrics email each subject an individualized URL for the survey? When the subject opens the URL, will the subject see only the faces assigned to him or her?

Comment: Answers to your questions are: yes and yes.